# Can't print MS Word read only file due to image on page

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, read-only

I am having an issue trying to print a read only Word file. When I click print, it hangs on a page where a image is and Word freezes. Removing the image allows me to print the document.

I have reinstalled Office, changed a setting to 'Print hidden text' due to Word thinking an 'In Line with Text' image is hidden, updated drivers/Windows and the problem persists.

Has anyone else encountered this and managed to fix?

Answer (score 2):

In any case the problem's clearly in the document. My best guess based on what you've done is that the original is some HUGE, uncompressed TIFF file which has just been re-sized in the page - that won't change the embedded file itself. Or something's gone funky when the doc was created, and it's mangling that part of the document.

Here's a few things to try:

1. Start the print job and when it hangs, just let it be. If it doesn't come out in half an hour kill it
2. Take a screenshot of the image, delete it and print the document. Then print the image separately from an image processing application
3. Delete the page and print the rest of the document. Then delete all other pages and try to print that page alone.
4. Copy-paste the text in the page to a new word document. Delete it, and print the rest of the document. Then insert the previous screenshot and print the missing page.
5. Print from start to the problem doc, then print from the prob doc to the last page, then print the prob page alone
6. Export the document to a PDF and print that

HTH